# ImportError in VENV while module shows in PP

Tags: python

I can't figure this out and I have read a lot of other post and know I am missing something simple.

I have a virtual environment created - Venv

When I pip freeze I get:

> requests==2.19.1                                                                                                                                       │
>   scandir==1.9.0                                                                                                                                         │
>   scipy==1.1.0                                                                                                                                           │
>   seaborn==0.9.0

`which python` = `~/jobs/unit/gate/venv/bin/python`

`which pip` = `~/jobs/unit/gate/venv/bin/pip`

`pip show requests` = `location : ~/jobs/unit/gate/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

default python = `Python 2.7.5`

I am trying to import a script that calls requests and I am getting ImportError: No module named requests

I checked my PYTHONPATH and I see the `~/jobs/unit/gate/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

I am lost of what to look for next? What else do I need to check

Comment: run `pip show requests` it will show you if the library is installed and where. There could be an issue for multiple python versions in the OS. Also run `python` in terminal to see which one is the default.

Comment: added those above

Comment: Interesting. Can you run this in your script `import sys` `print sys.executable`?

Comment: I get ~/jobs/unit/gate/venv/bin/python

Comment: I guess you already tried to uninstall and install the library again. I like to run `pip install --ignore-installed <library_name>` to solve similar issues.